# Security risk of running trac with tracd

Tags: apache-2.2, trac

I'm building a subversion repository server for a software project I'm working on and I want to use trac. I've successfully installed trac, and it runs using the tracd utility - but I'm guessing this isn't very secure. I'm concerned about evesdropping and I want to use trac over an HTTPS/TLS connection.

Is the only way to accomplish this using a webserver like apache? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache (+ mod_ssl) is not the only choice, but something will need to be listening on tcp/443. it is probably the most widely deployed, best understood web server out there, so it's not a bad choice.

Apache + mod_wsgi is excellent:
http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModWSGI